# lexical this and closures

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I'm trying to understand how the arrow function passed to `setTimeout`, remembers the value of `this` from the previous execution context. I know that the `this` value is looked up using lexical scoping rules when executing arrow functions. Does that mean the arrow function closes over variables and the this keyword?

```
var obj = {
  name: 'TestName',
  func: function() {
    console.log(this)
    setTimeout(() => console.log(this), 1000)
  }
}

obj.func() //{name: "TestName", func: ƒ}
```

Comment: In normal functions `this` is *not* looked up using lexical scoping rules. Arrow functions change this and save `this` in the closure.

Comment: thanks Barmar, I corrected the statement about look up

Answer (score 0):

Actually the whole point of using the **fat arrow notation** is to inherit the parent scope. Main application of arrow functions is to pull down the parent scope.
When we invoke a setTimeout the chain happens as follows-:

1. Call goes into **Call-Stack**.
2. It is transferred to **Web-Browser api** space, which waits till the interval time.
3. Now after interval time is completed it'll be handled by **Event-Loop** which will transfer it to **JS-queue**.
4. The command execution will wait till other items in queue finish executing and then it'll transfer the execution flow again to Call-Stack whenever it is empty.
5. Now the command inside setTimeout will be executed.

   [JS execution flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyPLx.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean the arrow function closes over the `this` keyword?

Yes, that's exactly what happens.